# Node.JS Transform Streams: Call External Function

Tags: node.js

I have a node.js transform stream that I'm trying to call an external function *populateNewCard* but I get an error that this function is not defined.  I'm not quite sure how I make *populateNewCard* visible to my transform function.

```
const transformCard = new Transform({
    objectMode: true,
    transform(card, encoding, callback) {
        this.push(populateNewCard(card)); //push card object to next stream
        callback();
    }
});
```

This external function is as follows in the same file:

```
exports.populateNewCard = (card) => {
    if(card.lang === "en" 
        && !card.digital 
        && card.set_type !== "token" 
        && card.set_type !== "memorabilia"
    ) {
        ...
    }
};
```

The whole picture is that I'm taking data from a JSON file that's about 13mb in size, creating a new json object, and then trying to write this object to a collection in MongoDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you declared the functions on the `exports` object, you'll need to call it the same:

```
this.push(exports.populateNewCard(card));
```

Usually though, I find separating functions and export is cleaner:

```
function populateNewCard() { ... }
exports.populateNewCard = populateNewCard;
```

And now with native ESM modules support, `export function populateNewCard() {}` will do both with a single line.

Comment: Ah, thank you very much.  JS is always so hard to leave for a while and come back to for me.